# Is JavaFX open source?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

When install JDK I found src.zip in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.xxx folder, but I can not find the javafx source code, I googled but found nothing (on http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/)
So, is javafx open source, and where can I get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update Sep 202**

For further info see the closely related StackOverflow question:

- [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)

I'd close this question of a duplicate of the above one, but it has already been closed as off-topic and cannot be closed as a duplicate by me.  Regardless, the linked question hasn't been closed as off-topic as of now and provides more answers with more detail, so it is a better place to look if you need more information,

**Update Dec 2019**

For current information on Open Source JavaFX, visit https://openjfx.io.

The current open source code repository for JavaFX is at https://github.com/openjdk/jfx.

At the source location linked you can find license files for open JavaFX (currently this [license](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/LICENSE) matches the license for open JDK).

**Previous Answer**

As of February 2013, JavaFX is partially open source and should become almost fully open source over the next few months.  The source is hosted as part of the open-jfx project that you linked in your question.

The manifest of the tip of the JavaFX development branch for Java 8 is:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip

The same page has a zip link, which allows you to easily download the available JavaFX source as a zip file.

The JavaFX source code is not included in the jdk src.zip file currently, but should be eventually before Java 8 is released.

*Update*

A [February 2013 update for JavaFX OpenSource status](http://fxexperience.com/2013/02/february-open-source-update/) has been published by the JavaFX development lead.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it is not open source in that it is free to change & distribute for any purpose. JavaFX is licensed for internal use, excluding what they call commercial features.

> *Use of the Commercial Features for any commercial or production purpose requires a separate license from Oracle.*

The license details for JavaFX are outlined in full [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html). (PDF version available from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html))

You can get JavaFX from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Isn't this true only for the binaries provided by Oracle? OpenJDK sources are covered by GPL + classpath extension, AFAIK, and OpenJFX is a part of OpenJDK.

Comment: You might be correct. That license information was linked from the Oracle binaries download site. If you are using an open source JDK, that is fine under GPL, but some source code from JavaFX is still proprietary. But as noted [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2012-December/005007.html), some parts have been open sourced.