# Is the JDK missing some source files?

Tags: java, javafx

I use Eclipse (Luna) with JDK 8 update 5, and I have started learning JavaFX. I was playing around with JavaFX media playback in the javafx.scene.media package - Media, MediaPlayer, MediaView, etc. classes - and I noticed there was no attached Javadoc for any of these classes: "Note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc." It seems like all the classes in the other JavaFX packages are fine and their Javadocs are attached properly. There are also 4 classes in javafx.scene.media that are working fine - AudioClipBuilder, MediaBuilder, MediaPlayerBuilder, and MediaViewBuilder (and those 4 are deprecated...) - but the rest of them are missing Javadocs.

I looked at the settings for jfxrt.jar and it has Javadoc location: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ and the source attachment is "javafx-src.zip" in the JDK. I checked in javafx-src.zip for the source files and the only files in javafx/scene/media were the 4 deprecated Builder classes that are working. So that explains why those 4 have working Javadocs, but my question is: why are the rest of the classes in the package missing source files? (And does anybody know of any other classes missing source files?) I reinstalled the JDK and they were still gone.

Also, even if the source files are missing, why is Eclipse still unable to find the javadocs, since http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ is set as the javadoc location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703220/is-javafx-open-source worth to look at ;)

Comment: I know that if you debug too deep in the "regular" Java classes you can run into missing source files, but so far all the ones I've run into have been in the `sun.*` package tree. I'm not really sure why stuff is still missing; I was under the impression that JavaFX was fully open-source with the release of Java 8. Perhaps Oracle just decided to not package everything for some reason; in any case, try downloading the OpenJDK source, as that should include everything.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the situation you are seeing was just a temporary bug and oversight in the internal Oracle JavaFX distribution construction build process, which will be rectified for future releases:

- [RT-37790: REGRESSION: Various source files are missing from javafx-src.zip](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37790)
- [RT-33865: REGRESSION: Media javadoc is missing](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-33865)

The issue tracker linked requires a signup, but anybody can sign up to view the issues at the referenced links.

Eclipse cannot find JavaFX JavaDocs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/, because the documentation is not there.  Currently JavaFX documentation is not integrated with Java 8 documentation.  JavaFX API documentation linked off the [Java 8 client technologies page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) points to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/, (strangely, this link resolved for me in Internet Explorer, but not Firefox).  I can see that the documentation for the JavaFX Media classes is there.

I'm not an Eclipse/e(fx)clipse user, so I'm not sure about the following, but I suggest updating your Eclipse javadoc configuration URLs to include the JavaFX API link.  It is possible that if you use the [e(fx)clipse tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/), the tools might configure the correct javadoc locations for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I updated the javadoc attachment to the separate JavaFX API documentation page and it is working fine now. As far as the missing files, it's good to know it is just a temporary mistake.

Comment: I fixed the javadoc location for the current dev stream (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439100)